# prove that every non-empty open set contains an open sphere disjoint from $A$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

> If $A$ is nowhere dense in $(X,d)$ then prove that every non-empty open set contains an open sphere disjoint from $A$.

Suppose that $A$ is n.w.d. in $X$ , and every non-empty open set say , $B$ contains all open sphere $S_r(x),x\in X,r>0$ such that $S_r(x) \cap A\not= \emptyset.$ Then where it contradicts ?

Comment: This has to assume that the topology is non trivial.

Comment: This is false in $\mathbb R^n$ because no sphere is open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B$ be an open set and suppose that every open sphere contained in $B$ intersects $A$. This means that every point of $B$ belongs to $\overline A$. In other words, $B\subset\overline A$. This is impossible, because we are supposing that $A$ is nowhere dense, that is, that $\overline A$ contains no open set (other that $\emptyset$, of course).

Answer (score 1):

If $U$ is a non-empty open set then $U\not \subset \overline A$ because $A$ is nowhere-dense. So the open set $U \setminus \overline A$ is not empty, and any non-empty open set is the union of a family of non-empty open balls.

Answer (score 1):

Let B be a non-empty open set. Suppose every open sphere inside B intersects A. Then every point of B belongs to the closure of A. But this contradicts the definition of a nowhere dense set.